# DERSet using BouncyCastle Java

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I've written below sample code to form `DERSet` using `bouncycastle`. Though I've added seq1 before seq2 , output DER buffer formed shows seq2 before seq1. If I change new `DERSet(seq4)` to `new DERSequence(seq4)` then output is in order seq0,seq1,seq2,seq3. Can someone please help me to understand why order is changing when I do `DERSet`?

```
ASN1EncodableVector seq0=new ASN1EncodableVector();
ASN1EncodableVector seq1=new ASN1EncodableVector();
ASN1EncodableVector seq2=new ASN1EncodableVector();
ASN1EncodableVector seq3=new ASN1EncodableVector();
ASN1EncodableVector seq4=new ASN1EncodableVector();

seq0.add(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("1.2.840.113549.1.9.3"));
seq0.add(new DERSet(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("1.2.840.113549.1.7.3"))); 

seq1.add(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("1.2.840.113549.1.9.25.3"));
String random1="167EB0E72781E4940112233445566778";
seq1.add(new DERSet(new DEROctetString(hexToBytes(random1))));

seq2.add(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("1.2.840.113549.1.7.1"));
String tmp="41303235364B30544230304530303030";
seq2.add(new DERSet(new DEROctetString(hexToBytes(tmp))));

seq3.add(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("1.2.840.113549.1.9.4"));
String messageDigest="5D98145E22FCB7F6751B1A453A30C52487F924BC75EF46DB7974C7AA6C4BC72D";
seq3.add(new DERSet(new DEROctetString(hexToBytes(messageDigest1))));


seq4.add(new DERSequence(seq0));
seq4.add(new DERSequence(seq1));
seq4.add(new DERSequence(seq2));
seq4.add(new DERSequence(seq3));

ByteArrayOutputStream bOut=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ASN1OutputStream dout=new ASN1OutputStream(bOut);
try{
    dout.writeObject(new DERSet(seq4));
    dout.close();
    String seq4Str= bytesToHex(bOut.toByteArray());
    System.out.println(seq4Str);    
}catch (IOException ex)
{

}
```

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: `DERSet` is sorted to maintain an unambiguous encoding. You could use an `ASN1Set`, but then you wouldn't be conforming to the DER.

Comment: Do you have any idea on what basis it does sorting?

Comment: Just found... DLSet encodes ASN.1 SET value without element ordering, and always using definite length form. It worked. Thanks Teppic !